# Problems installing front and rear Busch and Muller dynamo lights to a shimano hub dynamo

Tags: dynamo

I connected the Front Dynamo Light (Halogen Busch & Muller Lumotec Oval Senso) to the Shimano hub dynamo and it worked fine. I then connected the Busch & Muller D Toplight Plus Rear Carrier Dynamo  and got nothing from it. In addition the front light stopped working as well. If I only connect the earth cable from the rear light, the front one works, but once I connect both, nothing. Any ideas where I've gone wrong? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. To help us help you, can you provide a more detailed description / some photos of the exact set of connections you’re making?

Answer (score 3):

This combination of all three parts is on plenty of bikes. If the polarity connections are all right (double check with the rear), something is probably broken or defective. You know the light and the hub are working, so that leaves the rear light as suspect. A good next step could be testing output to the rear light wires with a multimeter.

Make sure you're spinning the wheel fast for a while to test.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out the new rear light is faulty